# TableView - How to add a download button inside it

Tags: java, javafx, download, tableview

I want to know how can I add a download button inside a tablew view column, in a JavaFX GUI, so for each element I can acces a link and download the files I need.
[image]

For example, in the picture above, for each row, in the download column, I want to have a download button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a [Cell Factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty) and a [Cell Value Factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) for your `TableColumn`. 
The cellFactory is responsible for rendering the data it gets from the cellValueFactory.

```
TableColumn<YourDataModel, String> yourColumn = new TableColumn<>();
yourColumn.setCellFactory(tableColumn -> new DownloadCell());
yourColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().downloadProperty());

public class YourDataModel {

    private StringProperty download = new SimpleStringProperty();
    // additional fields

    public StringProperty downloadProperty() {
        return download;
    }

    public String getDownload() {
        return download.get();
    }

    public void setDownload(String value) {
        download.set(value);
    }

}

public class DownloadCell extends TableCell<YourDataModel, String> {

    private Hyperlink downloadLink;

    public DownloadCell() {
        downloadLink = new Hyperlink();
        downloadLink.setOnAction(evt -> {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(downloadLink.getText()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // exception handling
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String link, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(link, empty);

        if (link == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            downloadLink.setText(link);
            setGraphic(downloadLink);
        }
    }
}
```